# Mason CLI how to select from command prompt options?

Tags: flutter, dart, mason

[image: mason cli command prompt]

I can't select from command prompt options. I press tab and arrow keys but nothing happens.

[mason_cli](https://github.com/felangel/mason/tree/master/packages/mason_cli#readme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>J</kbd> for arrow down

<kbd>K</kbd> for arrow up

<kbd>Space</kbd> to pick

Comment: Oh vim navigation keys I didn't think of that. Thanks! Here is why vim uses [hjkl](https://catonmat.net/why-vim-uses-hjkl-as-arrow-keys)